# Draw rounded thick line with WebGL & Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, line, rounded-corners

I just started to fiddle around with WebGL and three.js.
I would really like to create a thick line, which has rounded corners and endings. (see example picture)

[image: Example Image with rounded line]

Unfortunately I see that firstly the LineBasicMaterial's linecap property does not really work.
[Three.js LineBasicMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TubeGeometry)

I started to think about using a tube, but then I think I will still not get a round cap...

Does someone have any ideas how I could create a line in the picture above? It does not necessarily have to made with three.js but WebGL would be a requirement. (I also want to animate this line further on...)

Thanks for any hints.

Cheers

Comment: 2d or 3d? If 2d I would go for the easiest approach: draw each line as a rectangle + 2 half circles. Otherwise there is stuff like https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard

Comment: There's this  http://labs.hyperandroid.com/efficient-webgl-stroking

Comment: unfortunately I need it to be 3d. One can imagine the image to have coordinates like (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1.2), (1, 0.25, 1.2), (1, 0.25, 0.3) starting at the vertex at the left side. Thanks for the links though. I'll check em out.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to draw 3d volumetric lines. The first is to do a vertex expansion in the shader. This is what the links in the comments do. Here is another one in case you need more material: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/05/webgl-rendering-of-solid-trails/.

Unfortunately it have visual artifacts when the line segment is viewed directly heads on. Check out the demo here: http://codeflow.org/webgl/trails/www/. Spin the scene around and you will notice some line segments facing directly towards the camera will spin rapidly. It looks a lot worse with a less noisy texture btw. If this is fine with you this is probably the preferred option.

The 2nd option is to just dynamically generate a capsule mesh for each line segment. Not much to say about it, beyond that this is a simple, abet somewhat inefficient method.

The 3rd option is to do a limited kind of ray tracing in the shader. Calculate the distance between the line segment and the fragment being shaded and we can use that to determine the appropriate color. Here is a [link](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=61) for that. Geometry shader is not currently supported in the webgl but there is nothing stopping you from generating the bounding line cuboid via javascript. Oh and if you need soft lines you probably need the `blend_minmax` extension. Probably the hardest method to setup but can be viewed at any angle and very customize-able compared to the other 2 methods.

Comment: There is also a lib specifically for Three.js called [THREE.MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine).

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Thanks for the hints though! We tried different things (e.g. a tubeGeometry with a BufferSubdivisionModifier from the three examples), but still it does not really produce what we want + its slow. Checked out the THREE.MeshLine, but I can't really figure out how to produce a result like the one in my image...

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko I was unable to implement this in forge viewer do u have any sample ?

Comment: got 404 for the first two links :(