# How to add thickness to object in autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have an object in viewer which looks like a line how can I replace that with a rectangle with same positions in forge viewer with different color

here is what I am expecting
[image]

I am aware of theming
var red = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);
viewer.setThemingColor(dbId,red);
but this only helps in changing the color along with this I am wondering how can I make that look bold or thicker or can replace with my custom svg

Answer (score 0):

The lines you see in Forge Viewer are actual 3D geometry, not an SVG.

Also, "thick lines" are not supported by Forge Viewer directly. You would need to take a look at whether three.js supports them or not. For example: [Draw rounded thick line with WebGL & Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352726/draw-rounded-thick-line-with-webgl-three-js).

Also, "thick lines" are a bit tricky in the WebGL world. They often have to be emulated by thin quads, and if too many, can negatively impact your application's performance.

Comment: I need to replace that 3D geometry with my custom geometry

Comment: Sure, but in order to do that you need to extract the endpoints of the original line geometry in Forge Viewer. That geometry is the standard `THREE.BufferGeometry` so you'll want to read the documentation for that class to understand how the data can be parsed.